# how to use one ExtendScript file in both After Effects and Illustrator

Tags: extendscript

I have a script for AI but when this script is finished i want it to proceed with another function in AE. how can i do this without running two scripts?

So the script has to do a function in AI and after that is done it has to do a following function in AE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Bridge Talk

```
var bt = new BridgeTalk();
bt.target = "aftereffects";
var script = "alert(app.version)";
bt.body = script;
bt.send();
```

You can look it up in the [Javascript Tools Guide](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf). This link is for CS5. You will find never versions online or you can open it from the Help menu in the Extendscript Toolkit.

Comment: tnx, it works but i can not run a function in AE after this script, how can I do this?

Comment: You will have to stringify your whole function and have it within your AI script or you need to build create some way to load another Script File. You could use `$.evalFile (path[, timeout])` you'll find it also in the javasript Tools Guide